# OpenSSL Sign with Serial Number

Tags: process, openssl, digital-signature

I'm trying to get a .crt file with some information, but unfortunately, i can't get a Serial Number generated.

[image]

I'd like to have a serial number generated, but not the same as the top one.

My CRT is generated with a PHP and I'd like to know what to put in my `openssl.cnf` to have the "same" process as the bottom one.

Comment: I don't believe a serial number is used in a CSR since its just a request. The issuer usually sets the serial number when it issues the serial number. (And check the question is OK. The original referred to the 0x00 in two places).

Comment: I don't really know how it works (I read some thing about that before asking.. But i didn't get all the things), well.. That's weird. I know that the second CRT was generated as the same process as mine. (With PHP), but i don't know how this is possible to have a "serial number" other than put one in the "$usercert = openssl_csr_sign(blablabla, $config, '06'); " which '06' is the SN.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of [openssl_csr_sign function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-csr-sign.php) put the serial into crt